# WooCommerce checkout "error processing checkout. Please try again."

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I face problem with woocommerce checkout page and I couldn't solve it. first I face endless spinning in checkout (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIVHs.png) so I solve it by adding this code to my style theme (BeMobile theme)

```
.woocommerce-checkout.bemobile .blockUI.blockOverlay {
    display: none!important;
}
```

after that error message appears when I try to place the order in final step (my payment option is bank transfer only). The error is:

```
 syntaxerror: Unexpected token <in JSON at position 0
```

all I find are the issue appears when I use static page as displayed homepage (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpl0V.png). Note: using two themes Avada theme for desktop and I face no problem with it at all and BeMobile theme for mobile devices. Only I face the issue with this theme (BemMobile) which required to activate Redux framwork plugin. So if I disable this plugin theme not working but the checkout have no issue and if I activate Redux framwork plugin the theme (BeMobile) works but the issue appears. One thing If I activate this plugin and not using static page for display homepage the issue not appear and the checkout can be done without error.

I try to solve json error by replace this code

```
 dataType: 'json'
```

with

```
dataType: 'text'
```

and the error message convert to be

```
error processing checkout. Please try again.
```

any Idea PLEASE

My system report:

```
`
### WordPress Environment ###

Home URL: http://omanacademy.net/home
Site URL: http://omanacademy.net/home
WC Version: 3.4.4
Log Directory Writable: ✔
WP Version: 4.9.8
WP Multisite: –
WP Memory Limit: 768 MB
WP Debug Mode: –
WP Cron: ✔
Language: en_US
External object cache: –

### Server Environment ###

Server Info: Apache
PHP Version: 5.6.37 - We recommend using PHP version 7.2 or above for greater performance and security. How to update your PHP version
PHP Post Max Size: 128 MB
PHP Time Limit: 120
PHP Max Input Vars: 3000
cURL Version: 7.59.0
OpenSSL/1.0.2k

SUHOSIN Installed: –
MySQL Version: 5.6.36-82.1-log
Max Upload Size: 128 MB
Default Timezone is UTC: ✔
fsockopen/cURL: ✔
SoapClient: ✔
DOMDocument: ✔
GZip: ✔
Multibyte String: ✔
Remote Post: ✔
Remote Get: ✔

### Database ###

WC Database Version: 3.4.4
WC Database Prefix: wp_
Total Database Size: 10.98MB
Database Data Size: 9.40MB
Database Index Size: 1.58MB
wp_woocommerce_sessions: Data: 0.01MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_woocommerce_api_keys: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_woocommerce_order_items: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta: Data: 0.07MB + Index: 0.03MB
wp_woocommerce_tax_rates: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_woocommerce_tax_rate_locations: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_woocommerce_shipping_zones: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_methods: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_woocommerce_payment_tokens: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_woocommerce_payment_tokenmeta: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_woocommerce_log: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_commentmeta: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_comments: Data: 0.03MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_layerslider: Data: 0.07MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_layerslider_revisions: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_links: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_options: Data: 1.37MB + Index: 0.08MB
wp_pc_users: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_pc_user_meta: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_postmeta: Data: 2.15MB + Index: 1.19MB
wp_posts: Data: 5.00MB + Index: 0.14MB
wp_redirection_404: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_redirection_groups: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_redirection_items: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_redirection_logs: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_revslider_css: Data: 0.09MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_revslider_layer_animations: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_revslider_navigations: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_revslider_sliders: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_revslider_slides: Data: 0.21MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_revslider_static_slides: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sld_claim_configuration: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sld_claim_purchase: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sld_click_table: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sld_package: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sld_package_purchased: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_sld_user_entry: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_termmeta: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_terms: Data: 0.01MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_term_relationships: Data: 0.01MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_term_taxonomy: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_ulp_campaigns: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_ulp_campaign_items: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_ulp_layers: Data: 0.21MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_ulp_popups: Data: 0.06MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_ulp_subscribers: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_ulp_targets: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_ulp_webfonts: Data: 0.05MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_usermeta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB
wp_users: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.01MB
wp_wc_download_log: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wc_webhooks: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wiziq_contents: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wiziq_courses: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wiziq_enroluser: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wiziq_wclasses: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_woo_wallet_transactions: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_woo_wallet_transaction_meta: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wpforms_entries: Data: 0.01MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wpforms_entry_fields: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_wpforms_entry_meta: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_yith_wcmbs_downloads_log: Data: 0.00MB + Index: 0.00MB
wp_yith_ywsbs_activities_log: Data: 0.01MB + Index: 0.00MB

### Post Type Counts ###

ajde_events: 21
attachment: 284
avada_faq: 6
avada_portfolio: 6
custom_css: 1
customize_changeset: 4
dwqa-answer: 1
dwqa-question: 6
epsilon_gallery: 2
epsilon_galleryf: 2
epsilon_portfolio: 9
epsilon_portfoliof: 2
epsilon_quote_slider: 5
epsilon_slider: 1
epsilon_staff_slider: 2
faq: 20
hrf_faq: 2
nanodoc: 1
nanosupport: 2
nav_menu_item: 191
option-tree: 1
page: 330
pg_user_page: 2
post: 8
product: 12
responsive_accordion: 1
revision: 279
shop_order: 72
sld: 1
slide: 10
sp_html5video: 2
themefusion_elastic: 2
videoplayer: 1
wpforms: 2
yith-wcbm-badge: 6
yith-wcmbs-plan: 9
ywcmbs-membership: 2
ywsbs_subscription: 60

### Security ###

Secure connection (HTTPS): ❌
                    Your store is not using HTTPS. Learn more about HTTPS and SSL Certificates.
Hide errors from visitors: ✔

### Active Plugins (32) ###

Redux Framework: by Team Redux – 3.6.9
LayerSlider WP: by Kreatura Media – 6.7.6
WizIQ: by athuorGEN Technologies Pvt. Ltd – 1.1
Any Mobile Theme Switcher: by Dinesh Karki – 2.1
Arabic Woocommerce Middle east currencies: by t3rep.com – 2.3.2 – Not tested with the active version of WooCommerce
Arconix FAQ: by Tyche Softwares – 1.8.2
BeMobile Theme Core Elements: by Webbu – 1.0.1
DW Question Answer Pro: by DesignWall – 1.1.4
Epsilon Framework: by Webbu – 1.2.1
EventON: by AshanJay – 2.6.12
Fusion Builder: by ThemeFusion – 1.6
Fusion Core: by ThemeFusion – 3.6
FV Player: by  – 6.6.6
Layered Popups: by Halfdata
Inc. – 6.40

NanoSupport: by nanodesigns – 0.5.0
PrivateContent - Bundle Pack: by Luca Montanari – 1.039
Redirection: by John Godley – 3.4
Restrict Usernames Emails Characters: by benaceur – 2.6
Slider Revolution: by ThemePunch – 5.4.8
WaterWoo PDF Premium: by Caroline Paquette – 2.3.6
WooCommerce Max Quantity: by Isabel Castillo – 1.5.1 – Not tested with the active version of WooCommerce
WooCommerce: by Automattic – 3.4.4
WPForms Form Templates Pack: by WPForms – 1.0.0
WPForms Offline Forms: by WPForms – 1.0.0
WPForms Surveys and Polls: by WPForms – 1.1.0
WPForms User Registration: by WPForms – 1.1.0
WPForms: by WPForms – 1.4.7.2
YITH WooCommerce Uploads Premium: by YITHEMES – 1.2.2
YITH WooCommerce Badge Management Premium: by YITHEMES – 1.3.12
YITH WooCommerce Customize My Account Page: by YITHEMES – 2.2.10
YITH WooCommerce Membership Premium: by YITHEMES – 1.3.9
YITH WooCommerce Subscription Premium: by YITHEMES – 1.4.6

### Settings ###

API Enabled: ✔
Force SSL: –
Currency: OMR (OMR)
Currency Position: right_space
Thousand Separator: ,
Decimal Separator: .
Number of Decimals: 0
Taxonomies: Product Types: external (external)
grouped (grouped)
pvtcontent_plan (pvtcontent_plan)
simple (simple)
variable (variable)

Taxonomies: Product Visibility: exclude-from-catalog (exclude-from-catalog)
exclude-from-search (exclude-from-search)
featured (featured)
outofstock (outofstock)
rated-1 (rated-1)
rated-2 (rated-2)
rated-3 (rated-3)
rated-4 (rated-4)
rated-5 (rated-5)


### WC Pages ###

Shop base: #4097 - /?page_id=4097
Cart: #11940 - /?page_id=11940
Checkout: #11941 - /?page_id=11941
My account: #11942 - /?page_id=11942
Terms and conditions: ❌ Page not set

### Theme ###

Name: Bemobile
Version: 1.2
Author URL: https://themeforest.net/user/Enabled
Child Theme: ❌ – If you are modifying WooCommerce on a parent theme that you did not build personally we recommend using a child theme. See: How to create a child theme
WooCommerce Support: ✔

### Templates ###

Overrides: bemobile/woocommerce/cart/cart.php version 2.3.8 is out of date. The core version is 3.4.0
Outdated Templates: ❌


                        Learn how to update
`
```